# Pass parametrs to string

Tags: php

I have string like this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(l.lead_id), 
    l.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, l.added_date, NOW()) as time_elapsed 
FROM 
    leads as l 
WHERE 
    (
        l.name LIKE '%Nastya%' 
        || l.first_name LIKE '%Nastya%' 
        || l.nick_name LIKE '%Nastya%' 
        || l.name_vorname_partner LIKE '%Nastya%'
    ) 
    AND l.is_active = ? 
    AND l.is_archive = ? 
    AND dont_show_in_list=0 
ORDER BY 
    datum_event asc`
```

And i have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [l.is_active] => 1
    [l.is_archive] => 0
)
```

How can i pass settings `l.is_active` and `l.is_archive` to string?

Comment: Use prepared statements and parameter binding. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I need just get ready string, cant use pdo, mysqli